# Displaying Titles and Contents Corresponding to Arrows in React Component

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, jsx, tailwind-css

I am currently working on a React component called PolitiqueContent, where I display information with arrows pointing to different sections. Each arrow is associated with a title and content, and I am facing difficulties in achieving the desired display.

This is my current code :

```
import React from "react";

const PolitiqueConeten = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      {/* First Arrows  */}
      {/* Title */}
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <br />
      {/* Content */}
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit,
        quibusdam?
      </p>
      {/* Third Arrows  */}
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga,
        laboriosam.
      </p>
      <img
        className="w-5/6"
        src="img/backgrounddPool.png"
        alt="backroundPool"
      />
      {/* Second Arrows  */}
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo,
        accusamus?
      </p>
      {/* Forth Arrows  */}
      <h2>Title 4</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas,
        perspiciatis!
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PolitiqueConeten;
```

**Output of my code:**

[image]

**I want like this:**

[image]

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to structure the JSX or modify my code to achieve the intended layout. Thank you in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a CSS grid system, with the image as a background. With both rows and columns defined, you can have the DOM order the same as the order implied by the numbering too.

```js
const PolitiqueConeten = () => {
  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-2 gap-x-96 gap-y-40 grid-flow-col bg-[url(https://i.imgur.com/BK7sWVj.png)] bg-contain bg-center bg-no-repeat w-[1077px] h-[546px] py-10">
      <div>
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit,
          quibusdam?
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit,
          quibusdam?
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit,
          quibusdam?
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Title 4</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit,
          quibusdam?
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<PolitiqueConeten/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, I can't find words to thank you for this wonderful work. You are an excellent programmer. Thank you so much